# Are questions about problems with a Fitbit on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

If I had a problem with my Fitbit, would it be on-topic to ask about it here?

[This was originally asked on Super User in this question.](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14014/are-questions-about-problems-with-a-fitbit-on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

We've certainly had a few well-received questions about [Fitbits](https://iot.stackexchange.com/search?q=fitbit+is%3Aq) here, and I would imagine any new question would equally be accepted here.

As the Fitbit is generally considered a 'smart device', it should be [on-topic](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at Internet of Things Stack Exchange. Take a look at some existing questions to get an idea of which questions work well here, and be sure to read our [Asking Tips](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Good luck!